# Go Http Handler is restarting itself during the execution of a command (cmd.Command)

Tags: flutter, go, kubernetes

Please, I have an issue on a golang web application.
I don’t understand why is happening

Here is the code of the http handler

[Updated from the comment of @colm.anseo about using context]

```golang
func (h *HttpServer) GenerateMobileApp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()

    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    pid := vars["id"]

    // Check if the project exists : gRPC - to Project micro-services - ask to project-api msvc
    // var project *models.Project
    // if project, err := h.projectClient.IsProjectExists() isProjectExists(pid); err != nil {
    var project *protos.ProjectReply
    idRequest := &protos.IDRequest{
        Id: pid,
    }
    project, err := h.projectClient.IsProjectExists(r.Context(), idRequest)
    if err != nil {
        h.JSON(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, fmt.Errorf("error when checking project existance"))
        return
    }
    if project == nil {
        h.JSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Errorf("project does not exists"))
        return
    }
    log.Println("Grpc downloaded Project : \n\t", project)

    // Save locally the downloaded project
    if err := h.store.SaveDownloadedProject(project); err != nil {
        h.JSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Errorf("error when saving the downloaded project"))
        return
    }

    // Download the repository
    if err := h.mobileAPP.CloneBoilerplate(project.Id); err != nil {
        h.JSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Errorf("error when cloning boilerplate"))
        return
    }
    log.Println("Project successfully clone ", h.mobileAPP)

    if err := h.mobileAPP.Update(project); err != nil {
        h.JSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Errorf("error when updating boilerplate"))
        return
    }
    log.Println("TODO - Update the project not done yet")

 
    apkGenerationDone := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        apkGeneratedPath, err := h.mobileAPP.GenerateAPK(ctx, project.Id)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error when generation APK")
            h.JSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Errorf("error when generating APK"))

            apkGenerationDone <- false
            return
        }
        log.Println("APK Generated correctly: ", apkGeneratedPath)
        apkGenerationDone <- true
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Println("[GENERATE_MOBILE_APP] context done, process timeout: ", ctx.Err())
        h.JSON(w, http.StatusRequestTimeout, "process timeout")
    // case <-r.Context().
    case <-apkGenerationDone:
        log.Println("[GENERATE_MOBILE_APP] successful")
        h.JSON(w, http.StatusCreated, "link of the play store app")
    }

    // Save in the DB the APK generated

    h.JSON(w, http.StatusCreated, "link of the play store app")
}
```

Here is the code of `h.mobileAPP.GenerateAPK(project.id)`

```golang
func (app *MobileAPP) GenerateAPK(ctx context.Context, projectID string) (string, error) {
    log.Println("[GENERATED_APK] Start : ", projectID)

    generatedAppFolder := fmt.Sprint("app-", projectID)
    generatedAppFolderPath := filepath.Join(CLONED_APP_FOLDER, generatedAppFolder)
    os.Chdir(generatedAppFolderPath) // (filepath.Join(CLONED_APP_FOLDER, projectID))
    log.Println("[GENERATED_APK] Changed Directory to : ", generatedAppFolderPath)

    log.Println("[GENERATED_APK] Running : flutter build appbundle")

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "flutter", "build", "appbundle")

    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stderr, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()

    cmd.Start()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        oneByteStderr := make([]byte, 100)
        for {
            _, err := stderr.Read(oneByteStderr)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("[GENERATED_APK][STDErr] stdout.Read error : ", err.Error())
                break
            }
            r := bufio.NewReader(stderr)
            line, _, _ := r.ReadLine()
            log.Println("[GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine() ", string(line))
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    // num := 1
    oneByte := make([]byte, 100)
    for {
        _, err := stdout.Read(oneByte)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("[GENERATED_APK] stdout.Read error : ", err.Error())
            break
        }
        r := bufio.NewReader(stdout)
        line, _, _ := r.ReadLine()
        log.Println("[GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine() ", string(line))
    }
    wg.Wait()
    err := cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("[GENERATED_APK] cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }

    return "", nil

}
```

You can notice that I am running a command flutter build appbundle  at `cmd := exec.CommandContext("flutter", "build", "appbundle")`

The issue I have is that that command doesn’t finish. During it’s execution, after a few minute the http handler restart from the beginning. Not the `GeneratedAPK` method but the whole handler `func (h *HttpServer) GenerateMobileApp` restart from the beginning thus causing many flutter build appbundle processes . And it stopped when the first one is done. And it makes the http handler too long.

[Added for a better understanding]

Here is the full log of the corresponding POD

```
2022/01/19 08:10:17 Guitou mobile generator
2022/01/19 08:10:17 NewHttpServer()
2022/01/19 08:10:17 Connecting to gRPC Project
2022/01/19 08:10:17 Successful connection to gRPC Project Server

********* STARTING HERE *****************
2022/01/19 08:21:27 Grpc downloaded Project : 
     id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:21:27 Save Download Project : 
    id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:21:27 [CloneBoilerplate] Start
2022/01/19 08:21:27 Already clone: [/home/guitou/app-generated/conf-61a867371b1331002c7595cc] 
 %!s(<nil>)
2022/01/19 08:21:27 Last clone folder removed
2022/01/19 08:21:27 [CloneBoilerplate] *** Let's clone it :  https://gitlab.com/guitou-app/mobile-templates.git

Enumerating objects: 25, done.
Counting objects:   4% (1/25)
Counting objects:   8% (2/25)
Counting objects:  12% (3/25)
Counting objects:  16% (4/25)
Counting objects:  20% (5/25)
Counting objects:  24% (6/25)
Counting objects:  28% (7/25)
Counting objects:  32% (8/25)
Counting objects:  36% (9/25)
Counting objects:  40% (10/25)
Counting objects:  44% (11/25)
Counting objects:  48% (12/25)
Counting objects:  52% (13/25)
Counting objects:  56% (14/25)
Counting objects:  60% (15/25)
Counting objects:  64% (16/25)
Counting objects:  68% (17/25)
Counting objects:  72% (18/25)
Counting objects:  76% (19/25)
Counting objects:  80% (20/25)
Counting objects:  84% (21/25)
Counting objects:  88% (22/25)
Counting objects:  92% (23/25)
Counting objects:  96% (24/25)
Counting objects: 100% (25/25)
Counting objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Compressing objects:   4% (1/24)
Compressing objects:   8% (2/24)
Compressing objects:  12% (3/24)
Compressing objects:  16% (4/24)
Compressing objects:  20% (5/24)
Compressing objects:  25% (6/24)
Compressing objects:  29% (7/24)
Compressing objects:  33% (8/24)
Compressing objects:  37% (9/24)
Compressing objects:  41% (10/24)
Compressing objects:  45% (11/24)
Compressing objects:  50% (12/24)
Compressing objects:  54% (13/24)
Compressing objects:  58% (14/24)
Compressing objects:  62% (15/24)
Compressing objects:  66% (16/24)
Compressing objects:  70% (17/24)
Compressing objects:  75% (18/24)
Compressing objects:  79% (19/24)
Compressing objects:  83% (20/24)
Compressing objects:  87% (21/24)
Compressing objects:  91% (22/24)
Compressing objects:  95% (23/24)
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24)
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Total 25 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
2022/01/19 08:21:30 [CloneBoilerplate] Finish cloning
2022/01/19 08:21:30 [CloneBoilerplate] End
2022/01/19 08:21:30 &{0xc0003c2930}
2022/01/19 08:21:30 Project successfully clone  &{0xc0003c2930}
2022/01/19 08:21:30 [UPDATE] Project Conf Path :  /home/guitou/app-generated/conf-61a867371b1331002c7595cc
2022/01/19 08:21:30 [Update] Start
2022/01/19 08:21:30 [Update] WalkMatch :  [files/AndroidManifest.xml.tmpl files/Appfile.tmpl files/MainActivity.kt.tmpl files/build.gradle.tmpl files/data_list_page.dart.tmpl files/init.dart.tmpl files/pubspec.yaml.tmpl]
2022/01/19 08:21:30 [Update] Updating files started
2022/01/19 08:21:30 

************* pubspec.yaml.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:21:30 

************* MainActivity.kt.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:21:30 

************* data_list_page.dart.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:21:30 

************* AndroidManifest.xml.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:21:30 

************* init.dart.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:21:30 

************* Appfile.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:21:30 

************* build.gradle.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:21:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:21:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:21:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:21:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:21:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:21:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:21:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:21:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:21:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:21:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:21:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:21:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:21:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:21:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:21:30 [Update] Updating files end
2022/01/19 08:21:30 [UPDATE] Deep copy of the boilerplate folder : app-{projectID}
2022/01/19 08:22:14 [UPDATE] Deep copy ends.
2022/01/19 08:22:14 [UPDATE] Load config.yaml
2022/01/19 08:22:14 [UPDATE] Config Loaded  {[]}
2022/01/19 08:22:14 [UPDATE] Moved the transformed files into the app-{projectID}
2022/01/19 08:22:14 TODO - Update the project not done yet
2022/01/19 08:22:14 [GENERATED_APK] Start :  61a867371b1331002c7595cc
2022/01/19 08:22:14 [GENERATED_APK] Changed Directory to :  /home/guitou/app-generated/app-61a867371b1331002c7595cc
2022/01/19 08:22:14 [GENERATED_APK] Running : flutter build appbundle
10.1.1.133 - - [19/Jan/2022:08:21:27 +0000] "GET /61a867371b1331002c7595cc HTTP/1.1" 408 18
2022/01/19 08:22:27 [GENERATE_MOBILE_APP] context done, process timeout:  context canceled

************* RESTARTING HERE ***********************
2022/01/19 08:22:27 Grpc downloaded Project : 
     id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:22:27 Save Download Project : 
    id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:22:27 [CloneBoilerplate] Start
2022/01/19 08:22:27 Already clone: [/home/guitou/app-generated/conf-61a867371b1331002c7595cc] 
 %!s(<nil>)
2022/01/19 08:22:27 Last clone folder removed
2022/01/19 08:22:27 [CloneBoilerplate] *** Let's clone it :  https://gitlab.com/guitou-app/mobile-templates.git

Enumerating objects: 25, done.
Counting objects:   4% (1/25)
Counting objects:   8% (2/25)
Counting objects:  12% (3/25)
Counting objects:  16% (4/25)
Counting objects:  20% (5/25)
Counting objects:  24% (6/25)
Counting objects:  28% (7/25)
Counting objects:  32% (8/25)
Counting objects:  36% (9/25)
Counting objects:  40% (10/25)
Counting objects:  44% (11/25)
Counting objects:  48% (12/25)
Counting objects:  52% (13/25)
Counting objects:  56% (14/25)
Counting objects:  60% (15/25)
Counting objects:  64% (16/25)
Counting objects:  68% (17/25)
Counting objects:  72% (18/25)
Counting objects:  76% (19/25)
Counting objects:  80% (20/25)
Counting objects:  84% (21/25)
Counting objects:  88% (22/25)
Counting objects:  92% (23/25)
Counting objects:  96% (24/25)
Counting objects: 100% (25/25)
Counting objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Compressing objects:   4% (1/24)
Compressing objects:   8% (2/24)
Compressing objects:  12% (3/24)
Compressing objects:  16% (4/24)
Compressing objects:  20% (5/24)
Compressing objects:  25% (6/24)
Compressing objects:  29% (7/24)
Compressing objects:  33% (8/24)
Compressing objects:  37% (9/24)
Compressing objects:  41% (10/24)
Compressing objects:  45% (11/24)
Compressing objects:  50% (12/24)
Compressing objects:  54% (13/24)
Compressing objects:  58% (14/24)
Compressing objects:  62% (15/24)
Compressing objects:  66% (16/24)
Compressing objects:  70% (17/24)
Compressing objects:  75% (18/24)
Compressing objects:  79% (19/24)
Compressing objects:  83% (20/24)
Compressing objects:  87% (21/24)
Compressing objects:  91% (22/24)
Compressing objects:  95% (23/24)
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24)
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Total 25 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
2022/01/19 08:22:29 [CloneBoilerplate] Finish cloning
2022/01/19 08:22:29 [CloneBoilerplate] End
2022/01/19 08:22:29 &{0xc000596690}
2022/01/19 08:22:29 Project successfully clone  &{0xc000596690}
2022/01/19 08:22:29 [UPDATE] Project Conf Path :  /home/guitou/app-generated/conf-61a867371b1331002c7595cc
2022/01/19 08:22:29 [Update] Start
2022/01/19 08:22:29 [Update] WalkMatch :  [files/AndroidManifest.xml.tmpl files/Appfile.tmpl files/MainActivity.kt.tmpl files/build.gradle.tmpl files/data_list_page.dart.tmpl files/init.dart.tmpl files/pubspec.yaml.tmpl]
2022/01/19 08:22:29 [Update] Updating files started
2022/01/19 08:22:29 

************* MainActivity.kt.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:22:29 

************* build.gradle.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:22:29 

************* AndroidManifest.xml.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:22:29 

************* Appfile.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:22:29 

************* data_list_page.dart.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:22:29 

************* init.dart.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:22:29 

************* pubspec.yaml.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:22:29 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:22:29  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:22:29 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:22:29  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:22:29 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:22:29  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:22:29 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:22:29  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:22:29 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:22:29  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:22:29 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:22:29  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:22:29 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:22:29  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:22:29 [Update] Updating files end
2022/01/19 08:22:29 [UPDATE] Deep copy of the boilerplate folder : app-{projectID}
2022/01/19 08:22:36 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  ��═══════════════════════════════════════════╗
2022/01/19 08:22:44 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()      5.3s
2022/01/19 08:22:45 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()   1,434ms
2022/01/19 08:22:48 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()   2,229ms
2022/01/19 08:22:52 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()      4.0s
2022/01/19 08:22:58 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()      6.5s
2022/01/19 08:23:00 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()   1,386ms
2022/01/19 08:23:06 [UPDATE] Deep copy ends.
2022/01/19 08:23:06 [UPDATE] Load config.yaml
2022/01/19 08:23:06 [UPDATE] Config Loaded  {[]}
2022/01/19 08:23:06 [UPDATE] Moved the transformed files into the app-{projectID}
2022/01/19 08:23:06 TODO - Update the project not done yet
2022/01/19 08:23:06 [GENERATED_APK] Start :  61a867371b1331002c7595cc
2022/01/19 08:23:06 [GENERATED_APK] Changed Directory to :  /home/guitou/app-generated/app-61a867371b1331002c7595cc
2022/01/19 08:23:06 [GENERATED_APK] Running : flutter build appbundle
2022/01/19 08:23:27 [GENERATE_MOBILE_APP] context done, process timeout:  context canceled
10.1.1.133 - - [19/Jan/2022:08:22:27 +0000] "GET /61a867371b1331002c7595cc HTTP/1.1" 408 18

************* RESTARTING HERE ***********************
2022/01/19 08:23:27 Grpc downloaded Project : 
     id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:23:27 Save Download Project : 
    id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:23:27 [CloneBoilerplate] Start
2022/01/19 08:23:27 Already clone: [/home/guitou/app-generated/conf-61a867371b1331002c7595cc] 
 %!s(<nil>)
2022/01/19 08:23:27 Last clone folder removed
2022/01/19 08:23:27 [CloneBoilerplate] *** Let's clone it :  https://gitlab.com/guitou-app/mobile-templates.git

Enumerating objects: 25, done.
Counting objects:   4% (1/25)
Counting objects:   8% (2/25)
Counting objects:  12% (3/25)
Counting objects:  16% (4/25)
Counting objects:  20% (5/25)
Counting objects:  24% (6/25)
Counting objects:  28% (7/25)
Counting objects:  32% (8/25)
Counting objects:  36% (9/25)
Counting objects:  40% (10/25)
Counting objects:  44% (11/25)
Counting objects:  48% (12/25)
Counting objects:  52% (13/25)
Counting objects:  56% (14/25)
Counting objects:  60% (15/25)
Counting objects:  64% (16/25)
Counting objects:  68% (17/25)
Counting objects:  72% (18/25)
Counting objects:  76% (19/25)
Counting objects:  80% (20/25)
Counting objects:  84% (21/25)
Counting objects:  88% (22/25)
Counting objects:  92% (23/25)
Counting objects:  96% (24/25)
Counting objects: 100% (25/25)
Counting objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Compressing objects:   4% (1/24)
Compressing objects:   8% (2/24)
Compressing objects:  12% (3/24)
Compressing objects:  16% (4/24)
Compressing objects:  20% (5/24)
Compressing objects:  25% (6/24)
Compressing objects:  29% (7/24)
Compressing objects:  33% (8/24)
Compressing objects:  37% (9/24)
Compressing objects:  41% (10/24)
Compressing objects:  45% (11/24)
Compressing objects:  50% (12/24)
Compressing objects:  54% (13/24)
Compressing objects:  58% (14/24)
Compressing objects:  62% (15/24)
Compressing objects:  66% (16/24)
Compressing objects:  70% (17/24)
Compressing objects:  75% (18/24)
Compressing objects:  79% (19/24)
Compressing objects:  83% (20/24)
Compressing objects:  87% (21/24)
Compressing objects:  91% (22/24)
Compressing objects:  95% (23/24)
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24)
Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Total 25 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
2022/01/19 08:23:30 [CloneBoilerplate] Finish cloning
2022/01/19 08:23:30 [CloneBoilerplate] End
2022/01/19 08:23:30 &{0xc0007928a0}
2022/01/19 08:23:30 Project successfully clone  &{0xc0007928a0}
2022/01/19 08:23:30 [UPDATE] Project Conf Path :  /home/guitou/app-generated/conf-61a867371b1331002c7595cc
2022/01/19 08:23:30 [Update] Start
2022/01/19 08:23:30 [Update] WalkMatch :  [files/AndroidManifest.xml.tmpl files/Appfile.tmpl files/MainActivity.kt.tmpl files/build.gradle.tmpl files/data_list_page.dart.tmpl files/init.dart.tmpl files/pubspec.yaml.tmpl]
2022/01/19 08:23:30 [Update] Updating files started
2022/01/19 08:23:30 

************* Appfile.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:23:30 

************* build.gradle.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:23:30 

************* AndroidManifest.xml.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:23:30 

************* data_list_page.dart.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:23:30 

************* MainActivity.kt.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:23:30 

************* pubspec.yaml.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:23:30 

************* init.dart.tmpl
2022/01/19 08:23:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:23:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:23:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:23:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:23:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:23:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:23:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:23:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:23:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:23:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:23:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:23:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:23:30 Execute Project  id:"61a867371b1331002c7595cc"  title:"testing stufff"  description:"Go there"  author:{email:"john.doe@email.com"}  xorms:{id:"61a8673a1b1331002c7595d0"  title:"Xorm 1"  level:"primary"}
2022/01/19 08:23:30  john.doe@email.com
2022/01/19 08:23:30 [Update] Updating files end
2022/01/19 08:23:30 [UPDATE] Deep copy of the boilerplate folder : app-{projectID}
2022/01/19 08:23:36 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()     35.9s
2022/01/19 08:23:37 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
2022/01/19 08:23:39 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()     31.6s
2022/01/19 08:23:40 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  Building without sound null safety
2022/01/19 08:24:12 [UPDATE] Deep copy ends.
2022/01/19 08:24:12 [UPDATE] Load config.yaml
2022/01/19 08:24:12 [UPDATE] Config Loaded  {[]}
2022/01/19 08:24:12 [UPDATE] Moved the transformed files into the app-{projectID}
2022/01/19 08:24:12 TODO - Update the project not done yet
2022/01/19 08:24:12 [GENERATED_APK] Start :  61a867371b1331002c7595cc
2022/01/19 08:24:12 [GENERATED_APK] Changed Directory to :  /home/guitou/app-generated/app-61a867371b1331002c7595cc
2022/01/19 08:24:12 [GENERATED_APK] Running : flutter build appbundle
2022/01/19 08:24:22 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()      7.7s
2022/01/19 08:24:22 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  Building without sound null safety
2022/01/19 08:24:22 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  
2022/01/19 08:24:27 [GENERATE_MOBILE_APP] context done, process timeout:  context canceled
10.1.1.133 - - [19/Jan/2022:08:23:27 +0000] "GET /61a867371b1331002c7595cc HTTP/1.1" 408 18

************* RESTARTING HERE ***********************
2022/01/19 08:24:31 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                          
2022/01/19 08:24:31 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  License for package Android SDK Platform 29 accepted.
2022/01/19 08:24:31 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  
2022/01/19 08:24:31 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  License for package Android SDK Platform 29 accepted.
2022/01/19 08:24:51 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  
2022/01/19 08:24:51 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)".
2022/01/19 08:25:51 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  "Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)" ready.
2022/01/19 08:25:51 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  "Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)" complete.
2022/01/19 08:25:54 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2022/01/19 08:25:54 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  * What went wrong:
2022/01/19 08:25:54 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  > Failed to create parent directory '/Users' when creating directory '/Users/maelfosso/Documents/Guitou/GitLab/mobile/mobile-app-boilerplate/build/app/intermediates/flutter/release/arm64-v8a'
2022/01/19 08:25:54 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  * Try:
2022/01/19 08:25:54 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  og output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
2022/01/19 08:25:54 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  
2022/01/19 08:25:54 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  Warning: Failed to download package!
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  * What went wrong:
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  > Failed to install the following SDK components:
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()    Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  BUILD FAILED in 2m 14s
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK] r.ReadLine()  Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            137.7s
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] r.ReadLine()  Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK] stdout.Read error :  EOF
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK][STDErr] stdout.Read error :  EOF
2022/01/19 08:25:55 [GENERATED_APK] cmd.Run() failed with signal: killed
```

Take a look at the section `********* STARTING HERE *****************` and `************* RESTARTING HERE ***********************` to notice that the handler it's restarting.

You can notice also that the even with the timeout the command `exec.CommandContext("flutter", "build", "appbundle")` is still running even after the context timeout.

Why such a behavior from `exec.CommandContext`?
How to stop the http handler after the context timeout ?

Comment: how you're capturing `stdout` and `stderr` seems very brittle. I've updated my answer below with some suggestions there.

Comment: @colm.anseo From what I read about `CombinedOutput` it returns the output after the command has been processed right?
That's not what I would like to do. I would like to have the output in real-time because that output will be sent to the user in real-time, I mean line by line, as it is generated.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things of note:

- capturing `stdout` and `stderr` seems brittle (error handling from goroutine will not propagate properly)
- long running executable may cause request timeout issues

---

to capture `stdout` and `stderr` - I'd suggest using something like [exec.Cmd.CombinedOutput](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.6:src/os/exec/exec.go;l=557) e.g.

```
cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "flutter", "build", "appbundle") // see below for ctx details

var sout, serr bytes.Buffer
c.Stdout = &sout
c.Stderr = &serr
err := c.Run()
if err != nil { /* ... */ }

outBody, errBody := string(sout.Bytes()), string(serr.Bytes())
```

so no need for tricky wait-groups or complex error handling between goroutines.

---

You need to handle the case where web-requests may take too long. If a request is canceled (by the client or the server) - you need a mechanism in place to cancel the request's sub-tasks (e.g. you externally executed process)

When running any webservice always ensure to leverage `context.Context` for the lifetime of a request - especially when running any potentially blocking operations (as you are with `exec.Command`).

So first, from your handler, grab the request's `context.Context`, and pass this along to any potentially blocking calls:

```
func (h *HttpServer) GenerateMobileApp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...
    ctx := r.Context()  // context.Context for the lifetime of the request

    ...
    go func() {
        apkGeneratedPath, err := h.mobileAPP.GenerateAPK(ctx, project.Id) // <- add ctx
    }

}
```

and update your APK generator signature like so:

```
func (app *MobileAPP) GenerateAPK(ctx context.Context, projectID string) (string, error)
```

and to use `ctx` when executing an external tool:

```
//cmd := exec.Command("flutter", "build", "appbundle")
cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "flutter", "build", "appbundle")
```

with this in place, if the web request is canceled (times out - based on web server settings; or the client disconnects) the process will be terminated.
You can even have special clean-up logic in place for this occurrence, by checking the error from `exec.CommandContext` for either `context.Canceled` (client disconnected) or `context.DeadlineExceeded` (request timed-out).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: do you think that if the times out can cause the handler to restart again ?

Comment: I tried the CombinedOuput but with the same output
I updated the problem with the output

Comment: added log output

Comment: Sorry but with `exec.CommandContext` the command is not stopped when context timeout occurs

Answer (score 0):

To determine the place where the program hangs up add to your code:

```
func dumpStackAfter(interval time.Duration) {
        go func() {
                time.Sleep(interval)
                pprof.Lookup("goroutine").WriteTo(os.Stdout, 1)
                panic("timeouted")
        }()
}
```

And call it at the beginning of main function:

```
dumpStackAfter(time.Second*30)
```

Run you program and in 30 sec it will print stack trace which will show where the program hanged up.

Comment: sorry but the app is crashing and I don't understand the output, and the pod is no longer receiving the request.
what is it supposed to show me?
I would like to show you the output but I don't know how to do it in a comment